# i want to store javascript variable store in array like this is possible?

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to store javascript variables into arrays?

```
var ord1 = <?=$count1?>;
var ord2 = <?=$count2?>;
var ord3 = <?=$count3?>;

"data":[[1,ord1],[2,ord2],[3,ord3]]
```

What is the correct way of doing it? I can't seem to be able to store it in this way.

Comment: I think you are trying to create a json not array

Comment: You need to look at the generated JavaScript to see if it is right. YUou also need to look at the Console in your browser's developer tools to see if it provides you with any error messages.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense (it would be a syntax error), please explain what you mean by `"data":[[1,ord1],[2,ord2],[3,ord3]]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var array1 = [var1, var2, var3, var4];
var array2 = new Array(var1, var2, var3, var4);
```

Or

```
var array3 = new Array;

array3.push(var1);
array3.push(var2);
array3.push(var3);
array3.push(var4);
```

Comment: `new Array` is usually avoided because it's ambiguous,  consider removing https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript @Downvoter doesn't the first example explain how to create an array from existing variables? Don't think the downvote is warranted